# How can i develope following UI using UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Can someone help me in developing UI mentioned in screenshot using UICollectionView?
I think i will have to use Custom UICollectionLayout. But can someone give me kickstart?

Thanks.[image: desired UI on iPad/iPhone]

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12